# Set data in UNB segment EDIFACT

Tags: csv, biztalk, edifact

Do you know how I can set UNB in EDIFACT?

I have a CSV input file:

```
VRD1;100;200;0;0;L
```

And the output should be:

```
UNA:+.? '           
UNB+UNOA:2+100:14+200:14+200305:0704+00000000000000++AAA'           
UNH+1+INVRPT:D:96A:UN:EAN005'           
BGM+10::9+20200305070403+9
```

I have to map the second and third fields to UNB.

I appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the `EdiOverride` message context properties. You can find them in the `Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BaseArtifacts` assembly found in the BizTalk Server installation folder.

For instance, in an orchestration, you can do this:

```cs
EdifactMessage(EdiOverride.OverrideEDIHeader) = true;
EdifactMessage(EdiOverride.UNB2_1) = xpath(CsvMessage, ...); // 100
EdifactMessage(EdiOverride.UNB3_1) = xpath(CsvMessage, ...); // 200
```

Add a correlation set with the same properties to your send shape.

If you want to set them in a pipeline, use the property namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/edi-properties`.